# plotting graphs with x-axis of desired length in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to plot graphs in matlab, In hand, I had two raw data obtained from the market, say at year 0.25,0.5,0.75,1,2,3 and 4, corresponding values of product A are [0.9998,0.997,0.887,0.779,0.661,0.442,0.345] and B are [0.878,0.765,0.662,0.594,0.436,0.304,0.211] respectively. When I use

`plot([0.25,0.5,0.75,1,2,3,4],[0.9998,0.997,0.887,0.779,0.661,0.442,0.345],'k+',[0.25,0.5,0.75,1,2,3,4],[0.878,0.765,0.662,0.594,0.436,0.304,0.211],'b*')`

However, the graphs produced gives 4 lines. What should be done to fix the problem?

Comment: What is the problem?  The call to `plot` as you've written it produces **no** lines - just markers.  Do you want two lines for the two different time series?

Comment: It gives 4 plots on the same figure, [0.9998,0.997,0.887,0.779,0.661,0.442,0.345] as black, [0.878,0.765,0.662,0.594,0.436,0.304,0.211] as blue and [0.25,0.5,0.75,1,2,3,4] as blue dot. But I want [0.25,0.5,0.75,1,2,3,4] to be on the x-axis only

Comment: Sorry, you and I must be using different `plot` functions... the one that comes standard with Matlab produces no lines when the code snippet above is run.  Just a series of black and blue markers.

Comment: The built-in `plot` should not behave as you described. Run `which plot` and see which `plot` you actually executed.

Comment: I see. I will double check it. How about if I want to set the x-axis to be [0.25,0.5,0.75,1,2,3,4]? On the internet, I use xTicks, but my matlab say it is undefined function. I wonder if the version I used is not the latest one. My version is 2014a

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a graphic handler before modifying the XTick, Use the following

```
figure
ax = gca ;
plot([0.25,0.5,0.75,1,2,3,4],[0.9998,0.997,0.887,0.779,0.661,0.442,0.345],'k+',[0.25,0.5,0.75,1,2,3,4],[0.878,0.765,0.662,0.594,0.436,0.304,0.211],'b*')
ax.XTick = [0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1 2 3 4];
```